# Can't install bigrf package

Tags: r, installation, defunct

I'm having some extremely frustrating difficulty installing the bigrf R package.

I have tried the following:

```
install.packages('bigrf',repo='https://github.com/aloysius-lim/bigrf.git',type='source')
```

^^with dev mode on

```
install_github("aloysius-lim","bigrf")

install.packages("bigrf",source=true)
```

These have all been tried on R build 2.14 (which bigrf was built on), 2.15, 3.0.2 and 3.1.1
I am getting a not available for build x' every time.
***Is bigrf defunct?*** I have seen a couple of posts here on SO which have used various builds of R requesting help with bigrf. the solutions IO have tried came from these threads :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package ‘bigrf’ was removed from the CRAN repository.

Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.

Archived on 2015-11-21 as check problems were not corrected despite reminders from CRAN people that's what the note i get from the https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigrf/index.html

Answer (score 2):

To install the current version of `bigrf` on CRAN:

```
install.packages("bigrf", dependencies=TRUE)
```

To install the development version on GitHub:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("bigrf", repo='aloysius-lim/bigrf')
```

Comment: Awesome. You saved me some hair. Thank you :)

Comment: Oh dear. it seems i have bigger problems than this anyway. bigmemory, a bigrf dependency package has removed windows support :/
Does anyone know what the last version of bigmemory containing windows support is...??

Comment: You probably should post this as a new question.

Comment: It gets worse. bigrf, along with bigmemory are only available as UNIX packages now :(